# Make it so that a someone cannot react to a discord message until a channel has been deleted

Tags: discord, bots

So basically I have a support bot that creates a channel when someone reacts that only staff have access to. In order to prevent abuse I want to make it so that **a new channel channel cannot be created by the same person unless the a previously open channel is deleted.**

Answer (score 0):

Give your bot access to the AuditLogs will allow you to see who is creating the channels but I suspect that's not gonna help because the bot will be the one creating and deleting the channels, for the discord server he is the owner of the action.

Maybe the only way is to store in the bot code a map of the channel id and his owner (user that typed the command). With this every time a user try to create a new channel you can check on your map if there is any channel active for that user and if there is show some kind of error message.